# how to set the dropdown onload of the page

Tags: javascript

Hey I have a value in a variable in javascript. I want to set that value to the drop down list of the next page. I am executing this function in onload event of the body tqg. However I m not able to set the value.Here is the code..

```
function setdropdown(pay)
{

    alert("entered in jscrip"); 
    alert(pay);

     var selectBox = document.getElementById("payment1");

    alert(selectBox);    

    var len=selectBox.options.length;
    alert("abc");
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(selectBox.options[i].value==pay)
                {
                    selectBox.options[i].selected=true;
                    break;
                }
        }

    alert("success1");

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example works for me...
Have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tDu2J/

Do you execute this function after the pages has been loaded?

```
window.onload...
```